# How can I change the input before getting the error 503

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib

    

keywords = ['printer','tv','laptop','router','speaker','mobile','printer','tv','laptop','router','speaker','mobile']
```

When I try to scrape a website using a list of items I get results of only 3 items post which I get error 503. How can I get the results of 3 items and change 6.1 to 6.2 before getting the error  to get 3 more results  followed by Win64 to Win32 to fetch 3 more results and then change Mozilla to chrome and get 3 more results and so on...

```
    header = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }
```

Comment: Please add your full script for reference and try to explain your thought process

Comment: Seems to be duplicate [How can I pass in a list of words and not get the error 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71807192/how-can-i-pass-in-a-list-of-words-and-not-get-the-error-503) please do not spam.

Answer (score 1):

General approach to rotate `User-Agent`:

```
import requests, random

keywords = ['printer','tv','laptop','router','speaker','mobile','printer','tv','laptop','router','speaker','mobile']
user_agents = [
  'Mozilla/5.0',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'
]

for k in keywords:

    user_agent = random.choice(user_agents)

    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

    requests.get('<YOUR URL>', headers=headers)
```

*Be aware that amazon does not like such automated access to its pages and recognizes the patterns of access quite quickly. Of course, it would be even better to use an official API.*